# Read a zip file using FileStream then use CopyTo corrupts the file

Tags: c#, hex, filestream

Hi I am Reading a file from the user's computer then using specific network credentials to write it out to a network share this corrupts a very small percentage of the files.
when i open the files in a hex editor the hex is different on the first line

```
Header:    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
Good File: 50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 00 00 00 37 57 51 41 6f 61
Bad File:  50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 00 00 00 b7 56 51 41 6f 61
```

The difference in columns 0a and 0b exist throughout the whole file,

If I am going about this the wrong way by all means correct me or if it is just something small that would be better. Any help is much appreciated. The code I am using is below

```
var fileStream = 
    new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

var impersonationContext =
    new WrapperImpersonationContext("myDomain", "myname", "myPass");

        impersonationContext.Enter();

        try
        {
            using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(destination))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            impersonationContext.Leave();

            if(fileStream != null)
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How small is "a very small percentage" ? Did you try on different network and/or hardware ? It could be a simple write error on the hardware level.

Comment: It happens to 5 out of about 725 files, but it happens to those 5 files repeatedly on multiple computers. I will try writing to a different network

Comment: I agree with @driis. A good test for this would be to try [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) to see if the files get corrupted.

Comment: Is source a string?  What form are source and destination?  (I'm assuming source is a network share and destination is a local drive letter volume?)

Comment: source is a string unc path to the local copy of the file destination is the string unc path of the file to be writen

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on but if I delete the existing network file then run this process the file gets written correctly. If the corrupt file exists and the process tries to overwrite it the file that is written is corrupt.

Comment: If you put in a hard-coded test exception, does the dialog show up?  If not, you may have the file locked in some cases when it is corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileStream.CopyTo()` will write n bytes into the destination file, but won't erase the end of the destination file that previously existed.  Opening the output stream with `FileMode.Create` should guarantee an exact copy.

Calling `file.SetLength(file.Position);` at the end may also work, but I'm not sure how reliably...

Comment: This appears to have fixed the problem. Thanks a lot! Though from your explanation I would have expected the file to double in size when it is overwritten the first time but this is not the case. source file size was 29,902 and the corrupted file size was 29,967. also you wouldn't think this would only happen to a few files. Thanks for the answer Ill let you know if I find a situation where it doesn't work

Comment: @claybo.the.invincible It isn't pushing bytes, it's over-writing them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a .zip file header.  Recognizable is "PK", the initials of Phil Katz, the guy that invented the format.  The header format is [documented here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers).  The differences occur at offset 10.  Which is the "File last modification date".  A file having a different modification date is no great mystery and cannot easily explain the problem.